# Problems which use S₄ → S₃

Tags: big-list, examples, mathematics-education, symmetric-groups

I need examples of problems which use, directly or indirectly, the homomorphism $S_4\to S_3$ in the solution (its kernel is $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$).

Obvious candidates:

- Lagrange resolvent (the reduction of quartic to cubic equations).
- Tait's theorem on equivalence of 4-coloring of normal map and 3-coloring of its edges.

> Do you have more interesting examples?

Comment: constructing character table of $S_4$?

Answer (score 13):

I use this or something equivalent in teaching projective geometry to show that the cross-ratio has at most 6 distinct values (when the points are permuted) as opposed to the 24 naively expected. This involves checking that the elements in the Klein 4-group act trivially on the cross-ratio $R(A,B,C,D)$.